# Quote issues reading properties file using fmt:message in JavaScript

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I'm using  reading text from properties file. But when I'm using it in JavaScript like this:

```
alert('<fmt:message key="mykey" />');
```

If there's single quote defined in properties file for this key, there will be an error. If I change the single quotes to double quotes, the error will occur if double quotes defined in properties file.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to escape single quote in your properties file. Intead ofjava's try java''s. ie. two single quotes

Comment: We don't want to change the properties file. It's not good to use two single quotes instead of one single quote for localization, such as in Italian, the single quote belongs to the word.

Comment: Single quote should be escaped from server side.

Comment: Yes, but it's controlled by JSTL. Just trying to find out if there's JSTL functions can do this.

Comment: ${fn:replace(yourString, ''', '\\'')}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the same technique as handlebars: put your messages in <script> tags:

```
<script type="text/fmt" id="mykey"><fmt:message key="mykey" /></script>
```

then:

```
alert(document.getElementById("mykey").innerHTML);
```

Or, if you're using jQuery:

```
alert($("#mykey").text());
```

Comment: That would be OK if `<c:out>` was used to escape the HTML special chars in the message.

Comment: @JBNizet not needed, unless your message contains </script>

Comment: @MauricePerry Thanks. I think this can work. I tried to assign the value to a variable, but the problem for this is that there should be quotes for the value. But I'm still thinking of if there are other solutions, because I have lots of statement like this.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to dynamically escape the string using, for example, [Apache commons StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeEcmaScript%28java.lang.String%29). You could simply wrap this method into a custom EL function or JSP tag.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, this is a great solution if I can't find ways easier. Just wonder if there's JSTL function or something web technique can solve this.